# Можно ли поставить несколько break <line> под ряд в gdb?

Tags: gdb, breakpoint

Привет, господа и дамы. Не так давно начал пользоваться программой gdb для отладки программ на C++. Работаю на Linux (ubuntu 16.04 LTS). Каждый раз, запускаю программу и желая продебажить конкретную функцию построчно, я вбиваю break  на КАЖДУЮ строку в этой функции.

**Непосредственно вопрос** : Может, есть способ использовать break сразу на какой-то кусок кода (сколько-то строк под ряд), чтобы не заниматься каждый раз этой рутиной?
Т.е. вместо
break 1
break 2
break 3
break 4
break 5
break 6
break 7

, написать, например,
break 1-7

### ***Решено :***

**Оказывается, есть команда step, которая продолжает выполнение программы до следующей строчки в листинге. Я удовлетворен :)**

Comment: А это принципиально - использовать голый gdb, вне IDE и прочих гуев?

Comment: Если честно, то даже и не знаю. Раньше на винде программировал и было норм. Перешел на линуху и чувствую гораздо большее удовлетворение. Мне пока очень удобно пользоваться gdb. Думаю, что с опытом, может, и обращусь к гуишкам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Брейкпоинты можно расставить сразу, а потом запустить приложение.

Я так понимаю, что проблема в том, как выставить точку останова в произвольном файле в произвольном месте.  Для этого нужно просто правильно указать место

```
break <имя файла>:<номер строки>
```

Имя файла может быть как полный путь, так и относительный. Главное, что бы gdb нашел.

Сама команда break имеет дополнительные параметры, о них читайте в справке.

Если Вам нужно много-много раз запускать отладку с одними и теми же точками, то выставляете их один раз, сохраняете в файл (`save breakpoints <filename>`, поддерживается с gdb 7.2). Когда отладчик перезапуститься, то точки снова можно загрузить (`source <filename>`). Можно держать несколько файлов с точками останова.

Сам файл текстовый и можно его модифицировать в нужных направлениях.

Comment: Про сохранение точки - полезно.
Вопрос был в другом. Вместо того, чтобы писать
break 1
break 2
break 3
break 4
break 5
break 6

, хотелось бы иметь возможность написать что-то, вроде 
break 1-6

Comment: а какой смысл в подбных брейкпоинтах? можно же просто пройтись по  строкам пошагово.

С другой стороны, новые версии gdb поддерживают скрипты на питоне. А это открывает широкие возможности автоматизации.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html#Breakpoints-In-Python

Comment: Охохо. Точно! Я открыл для себя step! Я искал в разных источниках информацию о том , как можно управлять именно breakpoints и когда видел, что ничего нового именно в кусочке про breakpoints ничего нету, по отношению к предыдущему источнику, я искал дальше. Сейчас увидел, что на каждой странице, на которой бывал, ниже говориться и о пошаговом выполнении. Ух ты. Спасибо большое за помощь.

Comment: добавлю ещё одно там есть два варианта пошагового прохода - с заходом и без. А также есть команда "выполнять до выхода с функции".

Comment: Да, полезно. Благодарю. Читанул еще и об этом в гайде.

Comment: добавлю одну маленькую штуку. Если идет отладка пошаговая, то вводить постоянно команду step накладно. Можно просто нажимать enter - будет выполена последняя команда. А если к этому прикрутить команду watch...